# Существует ли аналог функции defineProperty в C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

```js
Object.defineProperty(
  Object.prototype,
  'reverse',
  {
    value: function () {
      if (this instanceof String) {
        let s = '';
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          s += this[(this.length -1) - i];
        }
        s = s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
        s.slice(1, this.length -1) +
        s.charAt(this.length -1).toLowerCase();
        return s;
      }
    }
  }
);

var str = 'Едрить';
var str2 = 'Идем молод , долом меди';
console.log(`${str.reverse()}\n${str2.reverse()}`);
```

Можно ли повторить этот код в C# без килотонны классов? Если да, то как?

Comment: ваши попытки решить вашу задачу?

Comment: Я не пытался, это сложно наверное. Js это весёлый язык, а с# грустный, так что нет, я подожду когда всё готовенькое дадут, а я скопирую

Comment: И зачем это вообще нужно?

Comment: Да прямо буквально почти всё можно повторить. При чём тут классы вообще?

Comment: нет, так это не повторишь а надо так.

Comment: Да ладно. Что, в `C#` нет цикла `for`? Ну вместо `slice` будет `Substring`

Comment: Я про Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype)

Comment: Как реализовать такой-же функционал в C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В C# тоже есть возможность добавлять новые методы не изменяя классов: [Extension Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```cs
public static class MyExtensions {
  public static string Reverse(this string original) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

```cs
string str = "abc".Reverse();
```